# play fadein/fadeout slider on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I have created a fadein/Fadeout slider. It's working find on auto. I want to play slider by clicking on next/prev buttons.

**HTML**

```
<section class="wrapper">
<ul class="slider">
    <li><img src="http://www.tylershields.com/images/gallery/art_gallery.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.goa-tourism.com/images/photogallery/1287634889_pid_kala%20academy%20art%20gallery.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.magnoliabakery.com/uploads/GalleryImageModel/105/filemask/mag1003_magnolia_fall_14original.gallery.jpg" alt="" /></li>
    <li><img src="http://www.lancasterconventioncenter.com/_images/_gallery/gallery15.jpg" alt="" /></li>
</ul>
<button data-dir="prev">Prev</button>
<button data-dir="next">Next</button>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
*               {margin:0; padding:0;}
.wrapper        {width:800px; margin:0 auto; max-width:100%;}
.slider         {position:relative;}
.slider li      {position:absolute; top:0; left:0; list-style:none; width:100%; opacity:0;}
.slider li img              {width:100%;}
.slider li:first-child      {position:relative; display:block; opacity:1;}
```

**Script**

```
var current = 0,
    elem    = $('.slider li'),
    slides  = $('.slider li').length,
    speed   = 3000,
    transSpeed = 1000;

function autoSlide(){

    current = (current == (slides-1)) ? 0 : +1;

    $('.slider').find('li')
        .filter(':eq('+ current +')').addClass('current').animate({'opacity':1}, transSpeed)
        .siblings('li').removeClass('current').animate({'opacity':0}, transSpeed);
    };

var timer = setInterval(autoSlide, speed);

$('button').on('click', function(){
    clearInterval(timer);
     autoSlide();
     timer =setInterval(autoSlide, speed);
});
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FU3Uj/3/)</kbd>

Comment: now what is happening on button click?

Comment: I had tried but not clear how to globally  increase and decrease the value of current on click of button.

Comment: @DhavalMarthak: var timer = setInterval(autoSlide, speed);

Comment: sorry for that I made it correct. [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FU3Uj/3/) check the update code

Comment: your function is having Semicolun. plz correct code first .

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in this line:

```
current = (current == (slides-1)) ? 0 : current + 1 // you were doing +1 which will always return 1
```

Your `current` variable was always set to `1`

Hope this will help!

[<kbd>Fiddle Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/FU3Uj/5/)

---

**Update**

To move previous and next you need to check which button is clicked as you're using only one handler for both, See below code:

You can get clicked element to the `autoSlidefunction(element)`

**Full code**

```
function autoSlide(element) {
    var clicked = $(element).text().toLowerCase().trim(); // Get next or prev
    if (clicked == "next")
        current = (current == (slides - 1)) ? 0 : current + 1; // Current will be incremented
    else
        current = (current == 0) ? 0 : current - 1; // decrease in current
    $('.slider').find('li')
        .filter(':eq(' + current + ')').addClass('current').animate({
            'opacity': 1
        }, transSpeed)
        .siblings('li').removeClass('current').animate({
            'opacity': 0
        }, transSpeed);
};

var timer = setInterval(autoSlide, speed);

$('button').on('click', function () {
    clearInterval(timer);
    autoSlide($(this)); // to get clicked element to autoSlide()
    timer = setInterval(autoSlide, speed);
});
```

[<kbd>**Updated Fiddle**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/FU3Uj/7/)

Comment: i want when prev button click it should goto previous image.

Comment: You have to check condition checking for that as right now you're using only button click so you have to check whether next is clicked or prev is clicked.

Comment: Dear @Dhaval Marthak I am stuck here, that's why I asked question. I am not so perfect in programing actually.

Comment: thanks dhaval for answer...but can pls explain how element parameter is working here...your just defined it but not pass any element than how it's taking button

Comment: @RakeshKumar Did you see my update again you will get an idea